# ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)

Tags: android

Im trying to check connection to the internet or if the device is connected to a wireless network.But **can not resolved getSystemService** error is occured.
Any advice ?

Full code is below,

```
 public boolean isConnected(){

    ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo =cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this in an Activity or Service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getSystemService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) is a method of `Context`.

Seeing as this can not be resolved, I can assume that you are not calling it from the context of an [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), which extends *Context* itself.

Whichever object you are currently in, needs to be passed the *context* object from the calling activity.

This object can be retrieved using [getApplicationContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()).

Comment: thanks, Im not calling in an activity. I handle it now